# How to make a clickable gmaps-for-rails map with a custom ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm using Google_maps_for_Rails in a Rails 3.2 app. I'm trying to implement a clickable map that updates lat/lon fields. I have this running in other parts of the app, but cannot get it to run under certain conditions. If the map has a non-default id, the clickable functions do not work.

I encountered this problem when trying to display two maps on the page. Both maps have a custom ID (i.e. not the default ID defined by the gem). One of the maps should be clickable to set the lat/lon fields, but this doesn't seem to work with the custom ids.

If I temporally revert the clickable map back to the default ID, the functions work as expected. But this is not a long term solution in my case.

I'm using the javascript suggested in the [gem's wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Javascript-goodies). I can't see anything obvious that defines the map ID that the function should apply to.

How can I define a map ID so that the function will apply to a specified map?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided:

> all javascript map objects are stored in the Gmaps object.
>
> To access these, simply type: Gmaps.the_map_id
>
> By default, it's Gmaps.map